# Как сделать условие корректным

Tags: java

Вопрос: как изменить код, чтобы он корректно работал. Основная проблема в инициализации массива.

Задача: Данные два массива строк a1 и a2 возвращают отсортированный массив r в лексикографическом порядке строк a1, которые являются подстроками строк a2.

Пример 1:

```
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

returns `["arp", "live", "strong"]`

Пример 2:

```
a1 = ["tarp", "mice", "bull"]

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]

returns []
```

Я понимаю, что код неправильный, а точнее в условии и присваивании. Потому что до этого не инициализировал, но можете подсказать как его отредактировать, чтобы было корректно.

Код:

```
public static String[] inArray(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < array2.length; c++){
                boolean got = array2[c].contains(array1[i]);
                if (got == true && array3[i] != array1[i]) {
                    String[] array3 = new String[] {array1[i]};
                System.out.println(array3[i]);
              }
            }
        }
            return array3;
    }
```

Comment: array3 используется до создания.

Comment: Да, прекрасно понимаю. Основная проблема в логике кода. Как её стоит поменять.

Comment: Логика правильная. Код неправильный.

Comment: Можете подсказать как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результирующем массиве не будет больше элементов, чем в первом массиве. Поэтому его можно сделать изначально равным ему, а потом, при необходимости, уменьшить

```java
public static String[] inArray(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
  String[] array3 = new String[array1.length];
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < array2.length; c++) {
      if (array2[c].contains(array1[i]) {
        array3[cnt++] = array1[i];
        break;  // Один раз вхождение нашли, дальше искать нет смысла
      }
    }
  }
  // если записали меньше элементов, чем размер массива
  if (cnt < array3.length) {
    // то создаем массив меньшего размера
    String[] tmp = new String[cnt];
    // и копируем в него элементы
    System.arrayCopy(array3, 0, tmp, 0, cnt);
    array3 = tmp;
  }
  // не забываем отсортировать массив
  Arrays.sort(array3);
  return array3;
}
```

Чтобы избежать приседаний с уменьшением массива, можно сразу использовать `List<String>`, а потом дернуть `.toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Логика, в принципе, правильная. Только нужно создать array3 (лучше как ArrayList, т.к. точная длина неизвестна) до циклов и в случае совпадения (`got == true`, а `array3[i] != array1[i]` выкинуть, это вообще непонятно что такое) добавлять в array3 нужный элемент. Если нужно без повторов, то в нужном месте вставить break.

Comment: Можете показать как правильно создать array3 до цикла? Просто мы ведь должны задать размерность, но она ведь неизвестна, потому что никто не может знать сколько будет совпадений из первого массива во втором.

Comment: Верно. Поэтому лучше создать ArrayList, ему длина не нужна и можно добавлять элементы.

Comment: Спасибо, именно такие мысли у меня и были до создания вопроса. Надеялся, что это я не совсем прав.

Comment: В данном случае `LinkedList` будет уместнее